# Porque no me muestra datos en columna SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: oracle, report, ssrs

deseo convertir una cadena en enteros en la consulta, dicha cadena contiene 0.0012455 pero el tipo de dato en la bd es varchar y no me deja realizar est SUM (B.VALOR_CAMPO) as campo,

estoy conectando a Oracle y al momento de usar: SUM (cast (B.VALOR_CAMPO as float)) AS CAMPO,
Oracle lo resuelve pero el SSRS me da error aunque solo use el cast, to_number

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo hay mucho que no sabemos acerca del problema para dar con una solución acertada, sin embargo, hay varias cosas que puedes hacer.

1. Siempre es bueno dar click al botón **Detalles**. El texto ahí contenido pudo haber sido de mucha ayuda.
2. Tendrás regiones/collations diferentes en ambos RDBMS? Puede que SQLServer tenga configurada una coma, en lugar de un punto, como separador decimal.
3. Asegúrate que en el SSRS tienes escrito

> SUM (cast (B.VALOR_CAMPO as float)) AS CAMPO

en lugar de

> SUM (B.VALOR_CAMPO)

Hay que mejorar la pregunta, o incluir más detalles, para escribir una respuesta satisfactoria. Espero esto te ayude

Comment: SUM (cast (B.VALOR_CAMPO as float)) AS CAMPO YA LO HE PROBADO  PERO  SIEMPRE QUE  ESCRIBO  CAST  O TO_NUMBER O CONVERT EL ERROR QUE ME SALE ES    ( ORA-01722: número no válido)